# In Windows 10 is there a way to share ZTE USB Modem internet connection?

Tags: networking, windows-10, hotspot, dongle

I have an EVDO ZTE USB Modem that connects to the internet on my Windows 10 laptop. The connection appears as a Dial-Up Connection so when I go to my Mobile Hotspot section of my Control Panel I get the message "We can't setup thre mobile hotspot because your PC doesn't have an Ethernet, WiFi or mobile data connection." All other options there are greyed/disabled. I would like to share this connection with Android devices.

If there a way to get my connection to be recognized as one of the whitelisted connection types (ie. Ethernet, WiFi or mobile data connection) so that I can use this Hotspot feature of Windows 10?

Comment: Have you tried to just bridge the modem and the Wi-Fi?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia could you explain further or share a link. Take into consideration the fact that I strictly want to use the laptop's Mobile Hotspot so that I can use it "on the go".